# Matching feature by ID from CSV

Tags: fme-form

I have a CSV-file with `"ID"`s. I would like to identify a feature in my database table that matches those `"ID"`s.

How can I use a tester/feature merger or something similar to get the records I am looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several solutions possible. One is:

1. Read the csv with the id's
2. Then read the database with a FeatureReader.

   - Fill the Where Clause to only read the matching features. (Otherwise you need to read all the records from the database and the power of a database is you can query it.)
   - Merge Initiator attributes with result, prefix initiators to prevent corresponding attributenames to overwrite each other.

[image]

[image]